# Matrix computation with for loop

Tags: r, matrix

I am newcomer to `R`, migrated from `GAUSS` because of the license verification issues.

I want to speed-up the following code which creates `n×k` matrix `A`. Given the `n×1` vector `x` and  vectors of parameters `mu`, `sig` (both of them k dimensional), `A` is created as `A[i,j]=dnorm(x[i], mu[j], sigma[j])`. Following code works ok for small numbers `n=40, k=4`, but slows down significantly when `n` is around `10^6` and `k` is about the same size as `n^{1/3}`.

I am doing simulation experiment to verify the bootstrap validity, so I need to repeatedly compute matrix `A` for `#ofsimulation × #bootstrap` times, and it becomes little time comsuming as I want to experiment with many different values of `n,k`. I vectorized the code as much as I could (thanks to vector argument of `dnorm`), but can I ask more speed up?

Preemptive thanks for any help.

```
x   = rnorm(40)
mu  = c(-1,0,4,5)
sig = c(2^2,0.5^2,2^2,3^2)
n   = length(x)
k   = length(mu)    
A   = matrix(NA,n,k)

for(j in 1:k){
    A[,j]=dnorm(x,mu[j],sig[j])
}
```

Comment: I'd be more concerned about memory than speed. Can you really run `A=matrix(NA,n,k)` with `n` and `k` at `10^6`? If my math is right you will need `.Machine$sizeof.long * 1e6 * 1e6 / 2^40` terabytes (7.3 on my machine).

Comment: Thanks for reply, flodel. I never thought about the memory problem. I confess I prematurely thought more is better when doing asymptotics, so I put 10^6. Actually, I am running this with condition `k^3/n→0` and `n, k→∞`. I want to experiment for `n=10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5` and if memory permits `10^6`. Thank you again for thoughtful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method can be put into a function like this

```
A.fill <- function(x,mu,sig) {
  k <- length(mu)   
  n <- length(x)
  A <- matrix(NA,n,k)
  for(j in 1:k) A[,j] <- dnorm(x,mu[j],sig[j])
  A
```

}

and it's clear that you are filling the matrix `A` column by column.
`R` stores the entries of a matrix columnwise (just like Fortran).
This means that the matrix can be filled with a single call of `dnorm` using suitable repetitions of `x`, `mu`, and `sig`. The vector `z` will have the columns of the desired matrix stacked. and then the matrix to be returned can be formed from that vector just by specifying the number of rows an columns. See the following function

```
B.fill <- function(x,mu,sig) { 
  k <- length(mu)
  n <- length(x)
  z <- dnorm(rep(x,times=k),rep(mu,each=n),rep(sig,each=n))
  B <- matrix(z,nrow=n,ncol=k)
  B
```

}

Let's make an example with your data and test this as follows:

```
N <- 40
set.seed(11)
x <- rnorm(N)
mu <- c(-1,0,4,5)
sig <- c(2^2,0.5^2,2^2,3^2)
A <- A.fill(x,mu,sig)
B <- B.fill(x,mu,sig)

all.equal(A,B)

# [1] TRUE
```

I'm assuming that `n` is an integer multiple of `k`.

## Addition

As noted in the comments B.fill is quite slow for large values of `n`.
The reason lies in the construct `rep(...,each=...)`.

So is there a way to speed `A.fill`.
I tested this function:

```
C.fill <- function(x,mu,sig) {
  k <- length(mu)
  n <- length(x)
  sapply(1:k,function(j) dnorm(x,mu[j],sig[j]), simplify=TRUE)
}
```

This function is about 20% faster than A.fill.

Comment: Thank you, Bhas for your answer with explanation in great detail. I learned interesting trick `all.equal`.

Comment: But unfortunately, in terms of speed, for `n=10^4` `k=21` it is not at all encouraging. On my computer, A.fill takes 0.04403901 secs, B.fill takes 0.6656001 secs as measured by `time <- Sys.time(); 
A <- A.fill(x,mu,sig);
Sys.time()-time`. I don't understand where that difference come from. Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: I think `B.fill` is slower because it needs to allocate memory for three additional huge vectors (of the same size as the resulting matrix).

Comment: I've done some more experiments and have concluded that what I do in `B.fill` is simply wrong. The length of `z` is not `n*k`. I'll see how this can be fixed.

Comment: I've changed `rep(x,times=F)` to `rep(x,times=k)`. That was the mistake. However `B.fill` is still slower than `A.fill` but a lot faster that the original `B.fill`.

Comment: @ExperimenteR: See my addition for a small speedup.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, @Bhas. This is the answer that I was looking for. I really need to learn `sapply` things. Thank you!